# How to plot dataframe in the matplolib framework with date format?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, matplotlib, format

I have the following dataframe

```
date;A;B;C;D
2017-01-01 00:00:00;    7.45;   52.78;   11.46;  502.44
2017-01-01 01:00:00;   23.95;   47.21;   11.45;  502.42
2017-01-01 02:00:00;    0.96;   44.72;   11.44;  502.44
2017-01-01 03:00:00;   26.67;   42.48;   11.42;  502.42
2017-01-01 04:00:00;   22.42;   38.86;   11.41;  502.40
2017-01-01 05:00:00;   17.50;   39.47;   11.40;  502.39
2017-01-01 06:00:00;   16.78;   42.47;   11.38;  502.38
```

I would like to plot it using the date and the column A. In particular I would like to customize the x-ax using date but with a fix interval and format, usind only Year, month and day. All in the matplotlib framework in order to use its feature.

This is what I have done:

1) Read the data frame:

```
DATAF = pd.read_csv(fnamed+'.dat',sep=';',index_col=0, header = 0)
```

2) then I plot it as

```
ax.plot_date(DATAF.index.values,DATAF['A'].values)
```

The results seems unreadable: [figure unreadable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v2eop.png)

One way could be convertong data index into data value but after that I don't know how to plot dates in the format that i want.

Thanks in advance,

Diego

Comment: You need to convert your strings to dates.

Answer (score 0):

@ImportanceOfBeingErnest is right. This is what I have done and it seem to work:

```
# Converting the index as date
DATAF.index = pd.to_datetime(DATAF.index)
ax.plot(DATAF.index.values,DATAF['A'].values)
```

Thanks a lot